# Availability Group Always ON 2016 HADR_SYNC_COMMIT

Tags: high-availability

I know it is not the best practice but we have a two node AG 2016 between two data centers. Server 1 and HQ and Server 2 at DR and they are clustered (multisubnet). AG is setup in Synchronous Commit mode. Everything was running okay for almost six months but the last two weeks most applications are running slow. I have around 40DBs in one AG. I observed a wait type HADR_SYNC_COMMIT one some of the transactions. They even stay for 30 seconds sometimes. I really dont want to lose data in case of failover and thats my only reason to keep them in Synchronous commit mode. I was wondering if anyone faced this kind of issue.

Comment: Check for network saturation on both your primary and secondary sides (along with any latency on the line), you'll find that lock occurs all the time, but shouldn't last long, generally it taking longer means the line is saturated and you cant get all the data through the connecting pipe